# Setting up SPF & DKIM with Parse.com

Tags: email, parse-platform, dns, spf, dkim

I'm trying to setup the SPF and DKIM on my domain's DNS Zone to make the parse.com emails send from **mydomain.com** instead of **no-reply@parseapps.com**.

> To ensure that mail providers don't incorrectly mark emails sent on behalf of your app as spam, we recommend you add DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail) and SPF (Sender Policy Framework) records to your DNS records.

Here's their explanation, but it's too vague for someone that isn't experienced with DNS, etc.

> 1) Run the following in your terminal: **dig +short k1._domainkey.parse.com txt** for the most up-to-date DKIM value.

First, it's unclear where the generated DKIM value (**"k=rsa\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQ...p7zmQIDAQAB"**) should go.

After doing some research, some people said to use **k1._domainkey** as the host name, some said **k1._domainkey.mydomain.com** (which "mydomain.com" gets trimmed automatically by GoDaddy's saving process), or **k1._domainkey.parse.com**

And I wasn't sure if I should keep the quotes around that generated DKIM value, because different examples either keep/omit them..

This is what I currently have under my **TXT (text)** section:
[image]

> 2) Add the following to your SPF or TXT record: **v=spf1 include:parseapps.com ~all**

As for the SPF, I already had an email provider like Mandrill or SendGrid, so it was unclear if I should create a new entry with "**@**" as the host name, or append it to the existing one? I tried many combinations, but all of them yield to emails that are sent from **contact=mydomain.com@parseapps.com**

[image]

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, this is driving me nuts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As for the SPF part you should only have ONE SPF record in the DNS. The SPF specifications state that multiple SPF records should result in PERMERROR.

So the "merged" SPF record should look like this:

```
v=spf1 a mx ptr include:secureserver.net include:parseapps.com ~all
```

You may also consider removing the ptr mechanism since the use of ptr is discouraged (since it may put a load on the receiving server).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, no matter what I try for SPF, the emails always come up from the "contact=mydomain.com@parseapps.com".

Comment: I think I partly misunderstood the original question. SPF has nothing to do with which mail-address is used as the sending address in your app/website. SPF only is used to verify which servers are allowed to send mail from the mydomain.com domain. The FROM address of your mails needs to be set up in your app or parse.com (I don't know parse.com, so I can't help you there).

Comment: Yeah I did set the FROM address to contact@mydomain.com in parse email settings, but it's not able to use it, which I think is coming from the SPF not being properly used in my DNS.

Comment: The SPF record is not used to change the addresses in the mail, but is only used by receiving mail servers to check the sending server. The format of the "contact=mydomain.com@parseapps.com" indicates that it's a combination of the address you have entered and the parseapps.com domain. So I would think that this is something that happens somewhere in the parse.com environment, and I would think this is something you could take up with the parse.com support. You can also try to inspect the headers of a received mail, to see if you can see if (and where) the address has been rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

emails that are sent from contact=mydomain.com@parseapps.com has nothing to do with SPF or DKIM signing so nothing with DNS configurations.
It has to do with sending software so check your parse.com soft that actually sends mail.
You have to check but it could be that you can have your own reply-to address when sending from parse apps but it can be, I didnt check, that parse doesnt allow to use your own domain as a send from address. If this is the case then correct signing with SPF and DKIM can help mails coming right.
So adjust and doublecheck your merged SPF record as in the answer above. And what I can see your DKIM record is correct.
You can test your mail is signed correct sending it to test address on [mail-tester.com](http://mail-tester.com)